# Reading object in json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, remoteobject

i have below  json which i get from Remote.

```
{

    "name":"planning Diet",
    "day1":{
        "morning":"chicken",
        "evening":"mutton",
        "night":"Juice"
    },
    "day2":{
        "morning":"burger",
        "evening":"pizza",
        "night":"Juice",
        "late night":"water"
    }

}
```

Below is what i tried.

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.com/hello.json",function(result){
  $.each(result, function(i, field)
{
console.log(field);
});
```

This returns something like

```
"planning diet"
[object object]
[object object]
```

Now how can i traverse or loop through all the object... ?

Comment: @oGeez : i need to add all those items in my html elements !

Comment: @Cerbrus : that url have answers which is really complicated ! i am expecting some easy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you can use something like this,

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.com/hello.json", function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        if (typeof field == "object") {
            console.log(i);  
            $.each(field, function(i, f) {
                console.log(f);
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log(field);
        }
    });
});
```

You can use `typeof field == "object"` to check the current item is an object or not

Comment: perfect ! will accept soon

Comment: hey ! how can i get object name ? that is day1 and day 2 ?

Comment: use the  `i` variable inside if condition

Comment: field where ?? console.log(field) gives object object

Comment: try `console.log(i)` inside if

Comment: no its returning "name"

Comment: wait i will give you a fiddle example

Comment: can you edit your solution please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/ZmzUB/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/ZmzUB/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need a function with recursive loop as below:

```
function getValues(obj) {
    if(typeof obj== "object") {
        $.each(obj, function(key,value) {
            getValues(value);
        });
    }
    else {
       console.log(obj);
    } 
}
```

Here you are basically doing this:

```
1) Iterate over the json item, check if item is an object. 
2) If so,iterate over this new object, else print the value. 
3) This goes on till all the values are printed and whole json structure is iterated.
```

The parameter to the function should be json which you get from remote location.

Answer (score 0):

```
var traverse = function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        if ($.isPlainObject(field)) {
            traverse(field);
        } else {
            console.log(field);
        }
    });
}
$.getJSON("http://domain.com/hello.json", traverse);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function traverse(obj){
   for(prop in obj){
       if(typeof obj[prop] === "object"){
           traverse(obj[prop]);
       }else{
          console.log(obj[prop]);
       }
   }
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rbs9A/

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop with `$.each()` only when you have got `[{},{},{}...]` multiple objects array, but in your case you just have a object which holds another object, so you don't have to do any iteration in a loop. You can refer with its `keys`:

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.com/hello.json",function(result){
   console.log(result); // gives you your object
   console.log(result.name); // gives you you "planning Diet"

   console.log(result.day1.morning); // gives you you "chicken"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
`field.day1.morning`

```
data=[{

    "name":"planning Diet",
    "day1":{
        "morning":"chicken",
        "evening":"mutton",
        "night":"Juice"
    },
    "day2":{
        "morning":"burger",
        "evening":"pizza",
        "night":"Juice",
        "late night":"water"
    }

}]
$.each(data, function(i, field){
alert(field.day1.morning)
})
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Aj9eJ/

Comment: no this is not traverse..its just getting particular item from json